# Image src and css href links not working in Web Previewer

Tags: css, image, visual-studio-code, hyperlink

I am just starting to learn HTML, so I am using a tutorial to do the basics.  I did everything as shown using Visual Studio Code 19 ending up with the following file structure and html:
**Projects 2
Portfolio>
  Blog
    <> index.html**  html follows -

```
<html> 
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf 8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css">
        <title>Web Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1 class="title">First Entry</h1>
        <p>May 22, 2020</p>
            <h2>Welcome</h2>
            <p class="highlight">This is text</p>
        <img src="../image.jpg" alt="Image without pic">
    </body>  
</html>
```

If I start a web previewer the image file and the css file are not used even though VS Code points to the following image file and css file in the main directory Portfolio.  The file structure following blog is: 
  **Portfolio>image.jpg
index.html and
css.html** index.html is the home page and uses the same css file and image file.  When previewed it works properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf 8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
        <title>Web Portfolio</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1 class="title">Web Portfolio</h1>
            <h2>Welcome</h2>
            <p class="highlight">This is text</p>
        <img src="/image.jpg" alt="image without pic">
    </body>  
</html>
```

**main.css** html follows

```
"h2 {
    background-color: #607d8b;
    color: #ffffff;
   }
   .title { font-size: 65px;}
.highlight {
           font-size: 16px;
           font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
           background-color: red;  
          }
```

Running the web previewer in the subdirectory blog on the file index.html does not display either the image file or use the css stylesheet main.css.  I have tried every way of referencing the files from the blog>index.html file /Portfolio/image.jpg, /image.jpg etc.  None of those options works.

However if I add the navigation links

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/blog">Blog</a>
```

to both index.html files and run the web previewer from the home page both the home page and the Blog page work as expected.  If I run the web previewer on the index.html file from the directory blog neither the image or css file is used.

So this way too long question is why is the index.html file in the blog directory not connected to the image and and css file when previewed.  The sample code was copied from a tutorial and the instructions were followed.  Even VS Code finds the files when you hover over the ../image with control click.  Is this a fault with the previewer?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGtp7.jpg)

[Blog.html preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTRKH.jpg)

Hey, so I took your code and tried Visual Studio Code. The image was corrupted in the index.html, I changed:

```
<img src="/image.jpg" alt="image without pic">
```

to

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image without pic">
```

But the blog page was formatted with the CSS and the image was there, so I think it's a preview problem, have you tried it on different browsers?
Personally i use google chrome.

Comment: I am using Chrome.  The only thing that did not work was running the blog index.html using the web previewer.  If I ran the root index.html with the navigation links everything worked as shown.  The /image.jpg worked as did image.jpg.  Not sure what if anything was corrupted?  Thanks for the comment.